# python pandas - Analyse period between two dates for other dates

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime

I have a start date and an end date (df_with_start_end) for a specific id and I try to figure which other dates with the same id from another dataframe (df_dates) are between them. The result should be entered in a new column.

The idea was I iterate over the dataframe df_with_start_end with the unique IDs and for every ID I try to analyse if there are any other dates from df_dates within the start and end date from df_with_start_end.

My implementation is like this,but it doesn't work that way.

```
for k in df_with_start_end['ID']:
    df_with_start_end[k]['FREE_PERIOD'] = df_with_start_end[k]['START_DATE'] <= df_dates[k]['DATE'] < df_with_start_end[k]['END_DATE']
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 3685509
```

Here is an example of the dataFrames:

```
df_with_start_end
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    FREE_PERIOD
1   2015-02-13  2016-02-13  False
2   2014-08-27  2015-08-27  True

df_dates
ID  DATE
1   2014-04-23
1   2015-08-02
1   2015-09-15
2   2014-06-19
2   2017-01-07
```

I heard loops are slow in python is there a way to avoid them in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you wish to iterate over rows but you actually do it over columns.

`for k in df_with_start_end['ID']:`
means `k` is an `ID` value.

However `df_with_start_end[k]` access the column whose value is `k`. Since your columns are only `START_DATE END_DATE FREE_PERIOD` you get an error that the value you seek does not exist.

A solution to that would be either to first access the column and then the `ID` by switching the order of your call:

`df_with_start_end['FREE_PERIOD'][k]`

But a nicer way would be to use the [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) function:

`df_with_start_end.loc[k, 'FREE_PERIOD']`

Comment: ID is a column too.

Comment: With your suggestion, now I get 
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [3609] is not in the [index]'

The value 3609 is a ID. Then I tried to get the index of the ID, but I get all the time errors.

Another idea is to join both dataframes ON df_with_start_end.ID = df_dates.ID ?

Comment: @haapoo, Is there a chance that the `ID` column is not your index column? Try setting: `df_dates.set_index([ID], inplace=True)` and same for `df_with_start_end`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way was to join the both dataFrames. For this join I used merge().
Then it's much better to compare them.
The problem was I tried to avoid to join them, but it looks like it's sometimes the better way.